# getting segmentation fault when copying arrays using std::copy

Tags: c++, arrays, stdcopy

i'm trying to carry out a pascal triangle, and i need to copy an array to an other, i'm currently using the copy function but getting the famous segmentation fault.

here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm> 
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    void print(const int *tab, const int &nbr){
        for(int i = 0; i<nbr;i++){
          cout << tab[i];
         }

        cout << endl;
     }


     int main()
     {
       int *tab;
       int *tab1;
       int index = 0;
       cout << "enter a number less than or equal to 20!" << endl;
       int number = 40;
       while(number > 20){
         cin >> number;
         cout << endl;
       }

       int a = 1;

       while(index < number){
         tab[0] = 1;
         for(int i=1;i<=index;i++){
            tab[i] = i;
         }
         print(tab,index);
         std::copy(tab,tab+index,tab1);
         index++;
       }

       return 0;
     }
```

I'm  getting the same error with memcpy function , can anyone

Comment: I'd recommend you should use a `std::vector<int>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @yes It is unclear what you are trying to achieve in the while loop.

Comment: imagine you have a phone book full of addresses of houses.. except there aren't any houses built on those lots and you tell someone to go sleep in one of the bedrooms at that address.   Not going to get much sleep

Comment: You can use `vector<int> tab = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`, `std::array<int, 5> tab = {1, 2, 3 , 4, 5};`, `int* tab = new int[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. I would advice vectors so you can do `std::copy_n(tab.being(), index, tab1.begin());` or `std:copy(std::begin(tab), std::end(tab) + index, std::being(tab1));` or `std::copy_n(tab.being(), index, tab1.begin());` . After all, you are doing `C++`, not `C`.

Answer (score 3):

(before your edition)

> getting segmentation fault when copying arrays using std::copy

The problem appears before the `std::copy`

Having

> ```
>  int *tab;
>  int *tab1;
>  ...
>  tab[i] = tab1[i];
> ```

*tab* and *tab1* are not initialized, they do not point to a block of memory used as an array, so the behavior is undefined (a segmentation fault in your case) each time they are dereferenced

Concerning the code about *number* you probably wanted something like

```
int tab[20];
int tab1[20]
```

Warning in

> ```
>  for(int i=1;i<=index;i++){
> ```

it seems you suppose the first index of an array is 1, while it is 0

---

A proposal from your code (after your edition) removing undefined behaviors, more some other changes, I commented the modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void print(const int *tab, const int &nbr){
  for(int i = 0; i<nbr;i++){
    cout << tab[i] << ' '; // add a space to separate numbers 
  }

  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int number;

  do { // your case it typically a "do while"
    // print moved inside to clearly indicate the expected input
    // even after a number invalid
    // and also request a  number > 0 else no sence after
    cout << "enter a number between 1 and 20!" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> number)) { // detect the error else if a non number you loop forever
      cerr << "invalid input" << endl;
      cin.clear(); // clear the error

      // bypass invalid input
      string s;

      if (! (cin >> s)) {
        // EOF !
        return -1;
      }
      number = 0; // to reloop
    }
  } while ((number > 20) || (number <= 0));

  int * tab = new int[number]; // added missing initialization
  int * tab1 = new int[number]; // added missing initialization

  for (int index = 0; index < number; ++index) {
    tab[0] = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=index; i++) {
      tab[i] = i;
    }
    print(tab,index);
    std::copy(tab, tab+index, tab1);
  }

  // free resources
  delete [] tab;
  delete [] tab1;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall cp.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter a number between 1 and 20!
aze
invalid input
enter a number between 1 and 20!
-1
enter a number between 1 and 20!
21
enter a number between 1 and 20!
20

1 
1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 2 3 
1 1 2 3 4 
1 1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

However in

> ```
> for (int index = 0; index < number; ++index) {
>   tab[0] = 1;
>   for(int i=1; i<=index; i++) {
>     tab[i] = i;
>   }
>   print(tab,index);
>   std::copy(tab, tab+index, tab1);
> }
> ```

*tab* is initialized a lot of times for nothing, it is enough to initialize each entry only one time

`std::copy(tab, tab+index, tab1);` is useless because *tab1* is never used.

It is possible to remove all concerning *tab1* and to just have :

```
tab[0] = 1;
for (int index = 1; index < number; ++index) {
  tab[index] = index;
  print(tab,index);
}
```

An execution under *valgrind* to check memory accesses and leaks (*tab1* removed) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==16633== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16633== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16633== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16633== Command: ./a.out
==16633== 
enter a number between 1 and 20!
10
1 
1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 2 3 
1 1 2 3 4 
1 1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
==16633== 
==16633== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16633==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16633==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 22,312 bytes allocated
==16633== 
==16633== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16633== 
==16633== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16633== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Also note you miss to print the last element in *print*

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i<nbr;i++){
> ```

can be

```
for(int i = 0; i<=nbr;i++){
```

Comment: sorry i edited my post, tab is initialized and i want to copy its content to tab1.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but the problem is not tab cause i can print its content by calling print function, the problem is tab1, tab1 is declared as a pointer so can i do  `std::copy(tab,tab+index,tab1);`

Comment: @lyes Well, _undefined behavior_ is _**undefined**_, that means anything can happen.

Comment: @lyes you missed to intialize them, do you understand the problem or not ? I think you imagine to have arrays like I say in my answer

Comment: @lyes I edited my answer with a corrected version of your code (as I can understand what you wanted)

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. You haven't allocated memory for `tab` and `tab1` before using them as though they point to valid memory. That causes undefined behavior.
2. <strike>You don't have any code for populating `tab` with data. Copying from `tab` to `tab1` does not make sense without that.</strike>
    The updated code initializes `tab`.

Comment: tab[0] is initialized, just forgot this line, it's why i start indexing at 1, the array is declared as a pointer , you mean i can't start populating it directly ?

Comment: @lyes, Yes, you can. I missed that.